# combine multiple $resource in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 resources in a factory like below.  The resources have the same root path but only differ in the invocation of the controllers and parameters. Only the Get is used in each of the resources. I wonder if there is a way to combine the resources into one and respond to three different Get.  Maybe configuring the 3rd param object (action) of $resource with the following spec, but I am not quite sure how.  Thanks.

```js
{
 getFacility: {method:'GET', params: { id: '@id' }, url: api.fsr + 'facility/:id'},
 getService: {method:'GET', params:{ id: '@id' }, url: api.fsr + 'service/:id'},
 getRole: {method:'GET', params:{ id: '@id' }, url: api.fsr + 'role/:id'}
}
```

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var moduleName = 'fsrFactoryModule';
  var factoryName = 'fsrFactory';
  var requiredModules = ["ngResource", "configModule"];
  var dependencyInjection = ['$resource', 'api', internalFunc];

  angular.module(moduleName, requiredModules)
    .factory(factoryName, dependencyInjection);

  function internalFunc($resource, api) {
    function facility() {
      return $resource(api.fsr + 'facility/:id',{ id: '@id' });
    }

    function service() {
      return $resource(api.fsr + 'Service/:id',{ id: '@id' });
    }

    function role() {
      return $resource(api.fsr + 'FSR/:id', { id: '@id' });
    }
    
    return {
      //usage: fsrFactory.facility()
      facility /*public method*/: facility /*internal method above*/,
      //usage: fsrFactory.GetService()
      service /*public method*/: service /*internal method above*/,
      //usage: fsrFactory.GetRole()
      role /*public method*/: role /*internal method above*/,
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can make a config object and use one  function to return the resource needed

```
var resources ={
   facility: 'facility',
   service :'Service',
   fsr: 'FSR' 

}

function myResources(name, id){
   return $resource(api.fsr +  resources[name] + '/:id',{ id: '@id' }).get({id:id});

}

return {
   myResources: myResources
}
```

Then in controllers:

```
$scope.data = fsrFactoryModule.myResources('facility', 123)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use the actions param as specified below but no sure if this is the correct approach.

```js
{
 getFacility: {method:'GET', params: { id: '@id' }, url: api.fsr + 'facility/:id'},
 getService: {method:'GET', params:{ id: '@id' }, url: api.fsr + 'service/:id'},
 getRole: {method:'GET', params:{ id: '@id' }, url: api.fsr + 'role/:id'}
}
```